# Oracle Apex: How to count detail records on a master-detail form

Tags: forms, validation, count, oracle-apex, master-detail

I'm building a Master-detail form in Oracle Apex.

There should be only a limited number of detail records for each master record; upto 4 detail records.

I can build a database trigger to ensure this business rule, but those error messages aren't displayed nicely in Apex (or even on the same page).

Is there a way to build an Apex validation to count and limit the number of detail records on a master-detail form?

Answer (score 0):

- Use a page level validation to count the number of records and
  display an error if required. A PLSQL function returning a boolean or
  error text will both work fine in achieving this.
- Use error handling to intercept the errors in order to display a
  user friendly message. This involves a bit more work but once you've
  got this up and running it'll be easily customised and ported over to
  other applications. You can find a tutorial [on Patrick Wolf's
  blog](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/apex-4-1-error-handling-improvements-part-1/) (one of the apex dev team; there is a part 1 and 2).

Comment: I'd like to do the count, as it seams the cleanest solution, but I don't know how to count the records. There don't seem to be any items available for either the detail records or the count of the detail records.

Comment: How is your page set up? When you create a master-detail page you will have the master record details in page items usually, while the details are in a tabular form. The master record's id will thus be in a page item, and you can use this page item in your select.

Comment: But won't that just count the records already in the database instead of the number of detail records entered on screen?